# Programmatically apply an ActiveRecord scope that accepts arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building a system where it is necessary to programmatically apply one or more where clauses to an ActiveRecord Relation object.  This works great in the following situation:

Assume the Employee model has scope called "male"

then:

```
filter_name = "male"
Employee.send(filter_name)  # works
```

However with scopes *that take arguments*,

```
"NoMethodError (undefined method `age_range(45, 55)'
```

e.g. with this scope:

```
scope :age_range, ->(low, high) {where("age >= #{low} AND age <= #{high}")}
```

The scope works fine in the console e.g.

```
Employee.age_range(45,55)
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I suggest also changing the scope into `where("age >= ? AND age <= ?", low, high)` to prevent SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Object#`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send) accepts the name of the method and its arguments:

```
name = :age_range
low  = 45
high = 55
Employee.send(name, low, high)
```

I would recommend to use [Object#`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send), to make sure you only use publicly accessible API:

```
Employee.public_send(name, low, high)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that!